# How to make my rock, paper, scissor run more than once

Tags: python

below is what I have so far, I need to implement function simul() that takes as input an integer n and simulates n rounds of Rock, Paper, Scissors between players Player 1 and Player 2. Any tips would be appreciated

```
import random
def simul(n):

    p1 = random.choice("RPS") 
    p2 = random.choice("RPS") 

    if p1 == p2:
       print("Tie")
    elif (p1 == "R" and p2 == "S") or (p1 == "S" and p2 =="P") or (p1 == "P" and p2 == "R"):
       print("Player 1 wins")
    else:
       print("Player 2 wins")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
def simul(n):

    for i in range(n):
       p1 = random.choice("RPS") 
       p2 = random.choice("RPS") 

       if p1 == p2:
          print("Tie")
       elif (p1 == "R" and p2 == "S") or (p1 == "S" and p2 =="P") or (p1 == "P" and p2 == "R"):
          print("Player 1 wins")
       else:
          print("Player 2 wins")
```

Comment: sorry, I need to input an integer on simul(n): and run the number of times n

Comment: @Jaime2823 as the statement was unclear, i made a few assumptions. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need recursive func. Simple solution is :

```
import random
def simul(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 'Finished'
    p1 = random.choice("RPS") 
    p2 = random.choice("RPS") 
    if p1 == p2:
       print("Tie")
    elif (p1 == "R" and p2 == "S") or (p1 == "S" and p2 =="P") or (p1 == "P" and p2 == "R"):
       print("Player 1 wins")
    else:
       print("Player 2 wins")
    simul(n-1)

n = int(input('Enter the number of rounds'))
simul(n)
```

Comment: Python doesn't do tail-call optimization, so this kind of recursion is not terribly efficient. In other languages, the compiler will often turn this into a loop, but in Python, you get a lot of unnecessary overhead with recursion that you can avoid using iteration instead.